# Prove existence of divergent sequence in Newton's method

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Given $ f(x)=x^3-1$, how to prove that there exists a sequence of initial values  $x_{0,1}>x_{0,2}>x_{0,3}>...$ where $x_{0,1}=0,x_{0,2}=-2^{1/3}$, such that the sequence produced by Newton's method is divergent?

Comment: Well, obviously if you pick initial values the wrong side of the inflection you are in trouble. Draw a graph.

Comment: So for $x<1$ you have $f(x)<0$ and $f'(x)>0$ so $N(x):=x-f(x)/f'(x)>x$. For $x>1$ you have $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)>0$ so $N(x)<x$. So to get divergence you would have to have oscillation; how might this happen?  (Contrary to @almagest 's comment, the issue is really about starting on the wrong side of an *extremum*, not an inflection point.)

Comment: Ok, I can 'see' it that way, but how do I strictly prove it? For every initial value $ x_{0,3}<-2^{1/3} $ the Newton's method produces an increasing sequence

Comment: @Ian What extremum?

Comment: @almagest There is no extremum, which is what my point was. A point of inflection in Newton's method could trigger oscillation, and it lowers the rate of convergence if it is at or near the root, but that's about it. It isn't necessarily a problem. (Is it possible that this is actually Newton's method for optimization and I misunderstood something?)

Comment: @user156336 Well, a simple way for it to happen would be something with period two, i.e. a solution to $N(N(x))=x$. Are there any of those? Edit: hm, that looks to be a hard way to proceed...

Comment: @Ian In this case, the problem is only that $f'$ has a zero (namely, $f'(0) = 0$). If you hit that point during the iteration - Boom. If not, at some step you'll reach a positive $x$, and then you're golden (since $f$ is convex on $(0,+\infty)$).

Comment: @Ian If you pick 0, you are clearly in trouble because $f'(0)=0$. So if you take a point where the tangent passes through the origin you are also in trouble and so on.

Comment: @DanielFischer Sure, if $y=mx$ is tangent to the curve at some point for some $m$ then you have a problem. But the problem isn't a divergent sequence, it's an ill-defined sequence.

Comment: @Ian A badly stated exercise. But apart from hitting $0$ (and then the fixed point $\infty$, if we look at the iteration on the real projective line), nothing else can stop the sequence from converging to $1$ for $f(x) = x^3-1$.

Comment: If you define $x_{0,3}$ by $x_{0,2} = x_{0,3} - \frac{f(x_{0,3})}{f'(x_{0,3})}$ then Newton's method with $y_0 = x_{0,3}$ gives $y_1 = x_{0,2}$ and $y_2 = x_{0,1} = 0$. This construction can be generalized to give you the desired sequence (see the commens above for why reaching $0$ is enough to give a divergence sequence).

Comment: So now the point is to prove the existence of a sequence such that $ N(x_{0,k})=x_{0,k-1} $, right? This way the Newton's method will hit from the first step the previous initial value, for which we have no conversion?

Comment: @user156336 That would give divergence but it is actually impossible in this case.

Comment: @Winther Why is it impossible? So winther is also wrong?

Comment: Yes that is the idea of the construction. There is one more step needed in the argument. You need to show that $c = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ always has a real solution (otherwise the sequence $x_{0,n}$ might not exist). However the equation above is equivalent to a qubic equation in $x$ for all $c$ and a qubic equation always have a real root.

Answer (score 1):

If we start at $x_0=0$, then the next member of the sequence is $-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}=-\infty$, so the method fails.

The line $y=kx$ is tangent to the curve at $x$ if $k=3x^2$ and $kx=x^3-1$, so $x=-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/3}$. So if we take $x_0=-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/3}$ we are also in trouble because the next approximation will be $x=0$ and then $-\infty$.

This process can be continued indefinitely, having found a bad point $x=-h$ we find a point on the curve whose tangent passes through the point $(-h,0)$. So we need a point $(-H,-H^3-1)$ such that the tangent there passes through $(-h,0)$. The gradient at $x=-H$ is $3H^2$, so the tangent is $y+H^3+1=3H^2(x+H)$. For this to pass through $(-h,0)$ we need $H^3+1=3H^2(H-h)$ or $2H^3-3hH^2-1=0$.

Put $g(x)=2x^3-3hx^2-1$. Then $g(h)=-h^3-1<0$ but the leading coefficient is positive, so there must be a root $H>h$. So we can find an infinite sequence of bad starting points.

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to justify that $H>h$ ? Also, I think that $g$ should be $g(x)=2x^3-3hx^2-1$

Comment: Then $g'(x)=6x^2-6hx$ has two roots $0,6h$ , and by the monotony of $g$ and the fact that $g'(0)=-1<0$ we conclude that $H\ge 6h>h$

Comment: @chkat Thanks, now fixed that typo. You can differentiate if you wish. I was just relying on the fact that $g(x)$ must be positive for large $x$, but is negative for $x=h$, so must have a root for $x>h$.